# Favicon not applied in safari

Tags: ico

I'm applying the favicon using React Helmet Async on the Bun js dev server, and I'm trying to apply the favicon file to Safari as an ico file. But safari doesn't work. However, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge work just fine.

However, when I apply the favicon in index.html, it works properly in safari.
Safari not reading React Helmet Async's dynamic favicon changes?

Here is my React Helmet Async application code.

```js
import IcoFavicon from 'assets/favicon.ico';
import SvgFavicon from 'assets/favicon.svg';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

<Helmet>
  <link rel="icon" href={IcoFavicon} />
  <link rel="icon" href={SvgFavicon} />
  ...
</Helmet>
```

I also used favicon.ico in index.html but it didn't work in both chrome and safari.

So I applied it in React Helmet Async.

Here is my old Index.html code.

```html
...
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> // I've tried both %PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico and ./favicon.ico as well as this path.
...
```

Comment: I've had many problems with Safari caching the favicon. For example, the dynamic favicon on Gmail that shows how many unread emails (not on by default) always shows `1` on Safari instead of updating properly.

Comment: If so, should I put the favicon in index.html?